# QWebEngineView in pyqt5 not work properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, fatal-error, qwebengineview

I create a pyqt5 window and add a QWebEngineView in it. This is the code I wrote in the init method of QMainWindow. Creating the object and connect its loadFinished signal to a method works fine, But the other two lines of code lead to error.

```
    self.browser = QWebEngineView()
    self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)

    self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.browser)
```

The error that the code encounters is:

*[13864:9100:0526/131403.948:FATAL:tsf_text_store.cc(52)] Failed to initialize CategoryMgr.*

Interestingly, this error does not occur when I run the code in debug mode.

```
python 3.7
PyQt5 5.15.4
PyQt5-Qt5 5.15.2
PyQt5-sip 12.9.0
PyQt5-stubs 5.15.2.0
PyQtWebEngine 5.15.4
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5 5.15.2
```

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class WebGameWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WebGameWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"))
        self.browser.loadFinished.connect(self.update_title)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

    def update_title(self):
        title = self.browser.page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle("% s" % title)
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I edit the question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: What do you mean by debug mode?

Comment: @eyllanesc In pycharm, it starts with Alt+F4. The mode that code will pause on breakpoints.

Comment: Okay, but that's just an illusion: Pycharm doesn't capture that output so it still exists.

Comment: @eyllanesc Consider that when I run it in debug mode, it starts and shows the web page. But when I run it normally, it just crashes.

Comment: It's probably a configuration problem in your IDE. I recommend running your script from the CMD or console to get the full error message.